# Java - is it possible to find thread with name and cast it to class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some problem with java.

for Example,

```
    public class Test implements Runnable{
        Thread thread;

        public Test() throws Exception{
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.setName(getClass().getName() + thread.getId());
            thread.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            System.out.println("start");
            try {
                while(!thread.isInterrupted())
                    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }

            System.out.println("stop");
        }

        public void stop() {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
}
```

this code now is infinite sleep status.
then, I find this thread by name in another Java code (something like this way - http://www.ehow.com/how_7467934_java-thread-runtime.html)

I casted "found thread" to Test class

> Test test = (Test)Found Thread;

finally,

> test.stop();

work!

**I want to find and stop this thread in the other application (absolutely not same)**

I`m not familiar with Java, also this like code way will not work in C++ or others as I know.

**Is my code in sense? no problem? I worry about...**

please advise me. thanx a lot.

(I`m not good at english. sorry)

Comment: Why dont you try compiling and running it? Then see what happens.

Comment: Why not simply keep a reference to your runnable and use it when you need it?

Comment: this code run well. I have done already.
I want to control thread from another application (not in same application)

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem in your code! Everything is just perfect. You may omit checking interrupted status of thread in sleep loop, because once thread is interrupted, it will going to throw that exception when it tries to sleep or wait.

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    Thread thread;

    public Test() throws Exception {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setName(getClass().getName() + thread.getId());
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("start");
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }

        System.out.println("stop");
    }

    public void stop() {
        thread.interrupt();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        Test t = new Test();
        t.stop();
    }
}
```